# How to get date string from stat command?

Tags: solaris, date, stat

I have this to get the timestamp of a directory:

`stat -c %Y directory_name`

What can I pipe this to, to get the date formatted like this?

`20220201`

Answer (score 4):

That `stat -c %Y` is specific to the GNU implementation of `stat`. If have GNU `stat` on your Solaris machine, it's likely you'll also have GNU `find` where you can just do:

```
gfind dir -prune -printf '%TY%Tm%Td\n'
```

You'll probably also have GNU `date`, with which you can do:

```
gdate -r dir +%Y%m%d
```

(though beware that if `dir` is a symlink, it will give you the modification time of its target, not the symlink itself).

Solaris also comes with `zsh` which has its own `stat` builtin (and has had long before a `stat` utility was added to GNU coreutils) where you can do:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -LF %Y%m%d +mtime dir
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
date --date=@$(stat -c %Y directory_name) +%Y%m%d
```

Comment: My version of date (on Solaris) doesn't have that option. I think I will have to use printf or strftime.

Comment: @CJ7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249827/convert-unix-timestamp-to-a-date-string/3249978

Answer (score 0):

You can embed it into a date command, e.g.:

`date  -d "@$(stat -c %Y directory_name)" +%Y%m%d`

But beware `stat -c` is a GNU extension, doesn't work elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `printf`:

```bsh
$ printf '%(%Y%m%d)T\n' "#$(stat -c %Y dir)"
20220127
```

Comment: That's only with the `printf` builtin of `bash`. `bash` copied that `%T` from ksh93, but in ksh93 (which is the `/bin/sh` of Solaris since Solaris 11), You'd need `printf '%(%Y%m%d)T\n' "#$(stat -c %Y dir)"`. Also note that `dir` is not the same as `dir/` when `dir` is a symlink.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, I was not sure about Solaris support. I'll edit with your advice.